# inserting pandas dataframe in oracle extremely slow

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, pandas

I am working on `pandas` dataframes. The goal of my application is to perform certain analysis on a csv file, and once that is done, insert this csv file into an `oracle` database.

To insert into an oracle database, I used `to_sql` command of `pandas` library. But to insert 300,000 rows, my code took around 2 hours and ten minutes. However when I used `MySQL` database for the same analysis and same size of input data, it took only 90 seconds.

I am doing all my operations inside a lubuntu VM. For reference, you can find relevant code below.

```
data_frame.to_sql(name='RSA_DATA', con=get_engine(), if_exists='append',
                           index=False, chunksize=config.CHUNK_SIZE)
input_data_list = get_rsa_object_list(data_frame)
```

I used same `CHUNK_SIZE` for both the cases (which was set to 500).

Can someone suggest what could be the reason for this and how do I get around this ? I cannot change my database system from `oracle` to any other database. I used `MySQL` just to be sure that the problem doesn't lie with my code.

Thanks in advance.

Following is the `CREATE TABLE` command for `Oracle` database:

```
  CREATE TABLE "CRISDEV"."RSA_DATA" 
   (    "GENE_SYMBOL" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "GENEID" NUMBER, 
    "CRISPR" VARCHAR2(75 BYTE), 
    "RSASCORE" NUMBER, 
    "LOGP" NUMBER, 
    "BEST_ACTIVITY" NUMBER, 
    "RSA_HIT" NUMBER, 
    "HIT_PER_GENE" NUMBER, 
    "TOTAL_CRISPRS" NUMBER, 
    "RSA_RANK" NUMBER, 
    "SAMPLE_NAME" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
    "FOLD_CHANGE" NUMBER, 
    "EXPERIMENT_NUM" NUMBER, 
    "CELL_LINE" VARCHAR2(75 BYTE), 
    "CRISPR_LIB" VARCHAR2(75 BYTE), 
    "CRISPR_LOT" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE), 
    "CAS9_VENDOR" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "CAS9_LOT" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE), 
    "CRISPR_INFECT_DATE" DATE, 
    "CAS9_INFECT_DATE" DATE, 
    "CAS9_MOI" NUMBER, 
    "FTE" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "SAMPLE_NAME_LONG" VARCHAR2(150 BYTE), 
    "INDICATION" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "LOW_CRISPR_COUNT" NUMBER DEFAULT 0, 
    "MODIFICATION" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "TIMEPOINT" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "CRISDEV_DATA" ;

  CREATE INDEX "CRISDEV"."C20150312_RSA_CELLLINE" ON "CRISDEV"."RSA_DATA" ("CELL_LINE") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "CRISDEV_IDX" ;

  CREATE INDEX "CRISDEV"."C20150312_RSA_CRISPRLIB" ON "CRISDEV"."RSA_DATA" ("CRISPR_LIB") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "CRISDEV_IDX" ;

  CREATE INDEX "CRISDEV"."C20150312_RSA_GENEID" ON "CRISDEV"."RSA_DATA" ("GENEID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "CRISDEV_IDX" ;

  CREATE INDEX "CRISDEV"."C20150312_RSA_GENESYMBOL" ON "CRISDEV"."RSA_DATA" ("GENE_SYMBOL") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "CRISDEV_IDX" ;

  CREATE INDEX "CRISDEV"."C20150312_RSA_SAMPLELONG" ON "CRISDEV"."RSA_DATA" ("SAMPLE_NAME_LONG") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "CRISDEV_IDX" ;

  CREATE INDEX "CRISDEV"."C20150312_RSA_SAMPLENAME" ON "CRISDEV"."RSA_DATA" ("SAMPLE_NAME") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "CRISDEV_IDX" ;
```

`CREATE TABLE` command for `MySQL` is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `RSA_DATA` (
  `GENE_SYMBOL` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GENEID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CRISPR` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RSASCORE` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `LOGP` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `BEST_ACTIVITY` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `RSA_HIT` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HIT_PER_GENE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TOTAL_CRISPRS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RSA_RANK` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SAMPLE_NAME` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FOLD_CHANGE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EXPERIMENT_NUM` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CELL_LINE` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CRISPR_LIB` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CRISPR_LOT` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CAS9_VENDOR` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CAS9_LOT` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CRISPR_INFECT_DATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `CAS9_INFECT_DATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `CAS9_MOI` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FTE` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SAMPLE_NAME_LONG` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INDICATION` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LOW_CRISPR_COUNT` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MODIFICATION` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TIMEPOINT` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Comment: can you provide `create table RSA_DATA ...` scripts for both Oracle and MySQL? I suspect you have some indexes, triggers and/or foreign keys constraints for this table...

Comment: @MaxU: edited my answer with relevant information.

Answer (score 3):

a few comments to your question:

1. you may want to play around with different `chunksize`'s
2. there are 6 indexes on the Oracle/ExaData side, which of course makes it slower
3. Check whether your ExaData is busy/overloaded doing something else during this load operation
4. You may try to load your data into temporary table and then copy it into your destination table. In case you don't have [data guard/standby/streams/golden gate] - you may also want to use direct-load (nologging): `insert /*+APPEND*/ into ...`
5. I would analyze the wait events (on the Oracle side) during this load in order to see where you spent time at most

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have tried using different `chunksize` 's, namely 50, 500 and 1000. Time taken was almost comparable in all the three cases.
Also, I have tried inserting into a table with no indexes: I created a table in Oracle without providing any index and tried to insert into that. It took same amount of time on that table as well.

Comment: @Rajat, i would try something like `10000, 20000, 50000, etc.`

Comment: I have also tried inserting into a table with no indexes: I created a table in Oracle without providing any index and tried to insert into that. It took same amount of time even on that table.

Comment: @Rajat, try to create a global temporary table - it should reduce amount of generated REDO dramatically, and pay attention at points: 3 - 5. I would start with 5

Comment: I tried using different `chunksize`'s, of the order of  2000, 3000 and 5000. There wasn't much change in the speed. Also, I don't have DBA access to the database to focus on point number 3-5.